# Why is child elements margin being applied to other cells?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem. Any child elements in a table cell with a margin and affecting every other cell. It's hard to explain, so check out this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s9nab3h/

```
<style>
    .table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table > .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
    .tallmargin {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        This cell has no margin or padding.
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p class="tallmargin">This content has a 100px margin on top.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: The problem was in `.table > .cell` I needed to have `vertical-align: top` since it defaults to `middle`.**

Comment: Interesting question. I just made a [test here](https://jsfiddle.net/5s9nab3h/4/) comparing an HTML table with a CSS table. As can be seen padding on one cell in a CSS table affects the position of the contents of the other cells. But it's not true for HTML tables...

Answer (score 1):

**display: table-cell** is setting the height of each column to equal size. You might want to read this [tutorial](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/) on table-cell

### Consistent height columns

By adding display: table-cell property Columns expand to match the **height of the largest column** in the row. The height is defined by the content and not an explicit fixed height.

Comment: Your answer made me realize what was wrong. In `.table > .cell` I needed to have `vertical-align: top;`.

Comment: True, but it doesn't explain why the vertical alignment of the contents of the former cell is affected by the latter.

Comment: The question is not about the height of the cells. It is obvious that table cells have the same heights. The main question is WHY the padding on top of a cell affects the vertical position of the contents of the other one, not only the height of that cell.

Comment: Nakib you didn't understand my original question though. I understood table cells always have the same height as their siblings, but it appeared setting a margin on the client `<p>` element was affecting the padding of the other table-cells. That wasn't the case though, it was actually just vertically centering the content in the other cells since `table-cell` defaults to `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe use float…

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table > .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;
}
.tallmargin {
    padding-top: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Then you'll miss the `display: table-cell;` as the computed value of `display` will be `block`.